# How to read the file when the first empty space occurs

Tags: java, readfile

I have a file whose content as follows:

Testing this program
This is the second line
"This is the Blank line"(Empty line)

This is first line that needs to read and stored
This is the second line that needs to read and stored

So as soon as Blank line is found, I need to start storing the data after the Blank line is detected.

I am using bufferreader and while loop to read line by line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
            FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(httpPost);
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

        while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
                if(line.trim().equals(""))
                {
                    //Read file after blank line is detected
                    modifieddata = modifieddata + "\n" + line;
                }
        }
```

Comment: post the code you've tried coming up with so we can help you from there.

Comment: I have added my code in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am not sure i completely understand what you're trying to achieve, but you are probably trying to do this :

```
 while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) 
 {  
      bufferdata+=  System.getProperty("line.separator") + line; 
      if(startSaving)
      {
           modifieddata += System.getProperty("line.separator") + line;
      }
      else  
      {
          originaldata += System.getProperty("line.separator") + line;
      }

      if(line.isEmpty())
      {
           startSaving = true; 
      }
  }

  if(modifieddata.isEmpty())
  {
      modifieddata = originaldata.trim();
  }
  else
  {
      modifieddata = modifieddata.trim();
  }

  String[] array = new String[]{modifieddata, originaldata};

  //Close the buffer reader
  bufferReader.close();

  // return array;
```

Comment: yes this is what I was looking for but I have other two issue once this problem got resolved. Issue 01: How to add new line character which is not dependent on Operating system after each line when I am reading each line and storing in Modifieddata? Issue 02: How to read first line of the Modifieddata?

Comment: For your first issue, you could use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` as it's OS independent.
As for your second issue, you could extract the substring from the beginning to the first newLine character encountered :  `System.out.println(words.substring(0, words.indexOf(System.getProperty("line.separator"))));`
I will edit my answer to this effect.

Comment: Thanks you it worked. I was just wondering, is it possible to remove first blank space from the string? I am new to Java so don't really know much about it. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: You're welcome... `words.trim()` should handle that.

Comment: Sorry I asked you wrong question..My problem is as soon as it finds a empty line it starts storing it in  modifieddata and it also stores empty line in the string modifieddata...so i am getting two new line character and then the data...so how to remove this two new line character from the start of string?

Comment: Even though I asked a wrong questions but you answered exactly what I needed...words.trim did the trick. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Apologies to bother you but i am stuck with another issue that came up when I was testing my code.There 2 types of files that may come 1st type of file: This file will have empty spaces in between the sentences & as soon as first empty space is found...this logic works fine. The 2nd type of file doesn't has any empty spaces in between the file but it has empty space at the end of the file so according to this logic my code is working for last empty space & I don't want this logic to work when empty space is detected at the end of the file and I simply want to store this data into modifieddata

Comment: Again, this is resolved...I just wrote a else for the if(startsaving)

Comment: You could have a second variable to store the lines read when `startSaving` is not yet activated. After reading the file, you could test to see if `modifieddata` is empty, if it's the case, then you output the content of the second variable, else you output the content of `modifieddata`.

Comment: Can you show how to do it? The solution which I told is not working correctly.

Comment: Thanks...this is how I was going to update my code after reading your comment...by the time I was updating you updated it...Thanks again much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I have deleted my comment as that was not appropriate on this question. @blazy due to some changes in the requirement...now i have to do the following...after this  while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) { i want to store watever data is present in the input file..so i am doing   bufferdata+=  System.getProperty("line.separator") + line; now my issue is i want to return this bufferdata as well as modifieddata...how can i return both the string from function?

Comment: I have updated my code....so that you understand what I meant...I want to return both bufferdata and modifieddata....how can i do that? I need to have both the data as they will be used in two different use.

Comment: @user3384231 You could return a String array, such that the content of `indice 0` is `modifieddata` and that of `indice 1` is `originaldata`. I'll edit the code to add the array. All you'll have to do is add `return array` at the end of your method.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick and my code is finally working. I was playing around with my code and trying new stuff....Can you tell how can I store first few lines of the file before the empty line in a different string variable?

Comment: Do you have some spare time to have a look at the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273484/how-to-read-xml-values-using-string-methods-of-java/23273654#23273654)

Comment: I think `originaldata` contains all lines read before the first empty line. Or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I had some other issue and I gave a link for that question to you :) no Problem I have fixed that and will update that question soon.

Comment: I have checked out the link and posted a possible solution.

Comment: thanks...Coincidentally I also gave my solution...at the same time.