# How to read XML values using string methods of Java

Tags: java, xml, string

I am looking for a way to search a string value from the following

```
<Test>
<Name>XYZ</Name>
<City>London</City>
</Test>
```

**Note that tags are not going to be repeated**.

The above contents are stored in a String. I want to write a java method which does something like this :

```
tagvalue = getvalue(<TagName>)

for example tagvalue=getvalye(Name)
```

Also, I want a method which will return the root tag (1st Tag from the string) i.e It should return `"Test"`.

I know Java parser and DOM can do this task but I don't want to use them. Can I simply do it by string manipulation method? or some other method?

The solution am trying is as follows :

```
//Method Call
String tag_value = getvalue(databuffer,"Name");

//Method

    private String getvalue(String Content, String Tagname) 
     {

            if (Content.contains("<"+Tagname+">"))
                {
                      if(Content.contains("</"+Tagname+">"))
                        {
                          //How do I get Tag value here? 
                 return Tagvalue;
                        }
                    }
        }
```

Another solution am trying is :

```
//method 
    private String getvalue(String Content, String Tagname)
        {
                //<Name>XYZ</Name> 
            int Starttag = Content.indexOf("<"+Tagname+">");//Returns 0
            int Endtag   = Content.indexOf("</"+Tagname+">");//Returns 9 
                //How to find the total length of <Starttag> so that I can subtract it with the index of Endtag to get the value?
            return ;
        }
```

Can I get any help from anyone please?

//**I have updated my question for namespace in the the element name...**

Input file will look like the following

```
<ns:Test>
<ns:Name>XYZ</ns:Name>
<ns:City>London</ns:City>
</ns:Test>
```

NOTE: I don't know the namespace that is going to come? it might be ns or np...anything..how to handle that? One thing i know is delimiter will be ":"

Is it possible to use string methods to simply ignore namespace in the element name to get the element value in the following logic?

Method call:
String elementvalue =  getElementvalue(databuffer,"Name")

Method:

```
public String getvalue(String buffer, String tagname) 
    {   
        String startTag, endTag,elementdata = null;
        int startposition,endposition;
        try 
        {
            startTag     = "<"+ tagname + ">";
            endTag       = "</"+ tagname + ">";
            startposition         = buffer.indexOf(startTag);       
            startposition         = startposition + startTag.length();
            endposition      = buffer.indexOf(endTag); 
            elementdata =  buffer.substring(startposition, endposition);
        }
        return elementdata;
    }
```

let me know if anyone can help me?

Comment: You could do it with string reading, recursive is probably best: read element's start <tag>, find the element's end </tag>, and recursively do the same for children tags.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you have written to try and implement the requirement

Comment: `I know Java parser and DOM can do this task but I don't want to use them` Why don't you want to use libraries that do the parsing job for you?

Comment: @jedison You might come across problems if you have two of the same tags though. Depends how sure they are that tags are not repeated.

Comment: @Trengot, I'm just going based on "Note:tags are not going to be repeated."

Comment: It sounds like you're going to end up writing another XML parser. If this is meant to be homework or an exercise then I guess the restrictions would make sense.

Comment: @Mxyl,@Alexis : I am not using Libraries because the xml file which I am reading contains some header information so when parser tries to parse it throws SAX exception and I cannot remove that header from the string.

Comment: @user2881767 I have updated my answer with the code I am trying...

Comment: @jedison: Do you have any comments on my updated question? Basically, i want to ignore namespace if i get any in the element name.

Comment: Hi, @user3384231, I'm back. That should be a relatively easy change, but I can only look at it tomorrow. OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input file

```
<Test>
<Name>XYZ</Name>
<City>London</City>
</Test>
```

Method call:
Tagvalue = getvalue(databuffer,"Name");

Method

```
public String getvalue(String buffer, String tagname) 
    {   
        String startTag, endTag,elementdata = null;
        int startposition,endposition;
        try 
        {
            startTag     = "<"+ tagname + ">";
            endTag       = "</"+ tagname + ">";
            startposition         = buffer.indexOf(startTag);       
            startposition         = startposition + startTag.length();
            endposition      = buffer.indexOf(endTag); 
            elementdata =  buffer.substring(startposition, endposition);
        }
        return elementdata;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I am looking for some method using string manipulation.

Comment: From my point of view Regular Expressions are a nothing else then string manipulation. They often provide smart solutions for tasks that require a few lines of code using only the String API.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with string reading, recursive is probably best: read element's start , find the element's end , and recursively do the same for children tags. As noted elsewhere, this could cause problems if tags are repeated.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking..can you please give some sample code to perform this operation...I am new to java..

Comment: I'm a bit hesitant to do that, as this often .equals("homework assignment"). We (most people on StackOverflow) prefer that you give it a try and ask for help when you're stuck. Read the string looking for "<" not followed by "/" and then read to the ">". That's your tag name; then find the matching "</" with this tag name. Of course, people are (rightly) suggesting using other tools like DOM, JaxB and RegEx.

Comment: Apologies for that...it is not homework..but yes thanks for the pseudo logic...I will try to implement it...Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Ok, I can provide you some code or review code that you write.

Comment: I have written my code...that I am trying..can you please review it?

Comment: Sorry, I was away (travelling). Seems like you got your code reviewed. Would you like a second review and some testing?

Comment: No worries. My code is working fine. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JAXB to do it. It requires more work upfront but that'd be the proper way to do it. The next best thing is Java DOM manipulation even though you do not want to use it.

Using regular expressions or String manipulation is dangerous because your XML might change.

Have a look at this [article](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am looking for some methods through String manipulation as my XML will never change and neither the structure will change.

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexOf(...)` instead of `contains(...)` and capture the returned values. Then you can get the tag value using `substring(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your second solution is more elegant. I modified your code and added some comments so you could better understand how to go about it.

```
private static String getvalue(String content, String tagname)
{
    // <ns:Name>XYZ</ns:Name> 
    int tagOpenIndex = content.indexOf(tagname + ">"); //returns the start index of the opening tag or -1 if it was not found
    int tagCloseIndex   = content.indexOf("</", tagOpenIndex); //returns the start index of the closing tag or -1 if it was not found
    String res = null;
   // How to find the total length of <Starttag> so that I can subtract it with the index of Endtag to get the value?
    if(tagOpenIndex != -1 && tagCloseIndex != -1 && content.indexOf(":" + tagname, tagCloseIndex) != -1){ // Firstly, you should be sure the opening and closing tags were both found in the String
         // The length of the opening tag = the length of the tag itself + 1 (the closing delimiter ">")
        int lenOpenTag = tagname.length() + 1;
        // the start index of the value enclosed in the tags is the start index of the opening tag + the length of the opening tag 
        int valueStartIndex = tagOpenIndex + lenOpenTag; 
        // you simply get the substring between the valueStartIndex and the start index of the closing tag
        res = content.substring(valueStartIndex, tagCloseIndex);
    }
    return res;
}
```

**Advice :** `try and cultivate the habit of starting your variable names with small letters except for constants.`

Comment: Can you see my updated question for namespace in element name?

Comment: @user3384231 I just updated my answer to handle the namespace.